# Conics classified by a group action.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-actions

Let $ \varphi : GL_2 ( \mathbb{R} ) \times \mathcal{M}_2 ( \mathbb{R} ) \to \mathcal{M}_2 ( \mathbb{R} ) $ be the group action defined by : $ \varphi (P,A) = PAP^{T} $.

What does it mean that the conics of the form :

$$ ( \mathcal{C} ) \ \ : \ \  f(x,y) = ax^2 + bxy+cy^2 + dx + ey + f = 0 $$

form an invariant class by the group action $ \varphi $, and are divided into three orbits: ellipses, hyperboles, parabolas? How to show that ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The set of conics of that form cannot be identified with $M_2(\Bbb R)$. You would have to specify conics that are *centered at zero* for that to make sense, in which case $d=e=0$ in that form. Or, you would instead have to consider an action of the affine group to talk about all conics. Perhaps you should give us a reference for what it is you're talking about.